# How to mask image source in inspect

Tags: javascript, php, html

I get name of the photo form database and i need to show fake name when i inspect it on website. Is it possibile in PHP or JavaScript to hide or hash image source?

```
<img src="img//<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the image is loading from a temporary source, there is no way to "hide" the image URL, otherwise the browser would have no way of knowing how to load the image.

Your options are:

1. Create a dynamic image that requires some kind of verification to see it (eg, session based).
2. Load the image content in PHP, then echo the contents as a base64 string inline into the `<img>` tag. Eg: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)